# Update browser when file change in LightTable

Tags: clojurescript, lighttable

I start using LightTable and as I understand there is a way to automatically update the browser when my ClojureScript source is changing. But I cant figure it out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice [documentation for LightTable](http://docs.lighttable.com/tutorials/full/). See the "Evaluating with JavaScript" section, where is also the evaluation of CSS and HTML into internal browser tab.